# Should I always let Spring container manage my objects?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I'm using Spring for some time already, and as much as came to like it, there is one thing I find really confusing. There are situations when I could make object I need a spring bean, but it makes things much more complicated. So is there any good rule for deciding if object should be injected or not?

Example I'm working on right now:

I have a OPC client bean using openScada utgard lib and separate bean containing connection settings. To start reading data from apc server I have to create `Server` instance, and passing `Server` instance to it's constructor a `SyncAccess` instance. I could create them as beans, but it doesnt seem to give mu much of advantage in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, making something into a bean gives you the advantage of being able to use it in multiple places, whether that's using `@Autowired` or injecting it as a declared property to another bean. You'd also get the advantages of easily being able to define it's scope (e.g. singleton vs prototype).

If you know for a fact nothing else will use your connection settings you don't have to use it, but if there's a chance for re-use, you're probably better off taking the time now rather than doing the re-work (or worse, copy/paste) later.